# Retrieve only metadata of pages of database

Tags: notion-api

I am trying to implement a feature in my app (See https://github.com/maxbethke/me/issues/9), for which I want to only query metadata from pages in a database, which include certain properties and the page id.
I am doing this in hopes to reduce response times and therefore make my app faster.
I would want to load the page details later using the id in a second request, when those are actually needed.

As far as I can see (https://developers.notion.com/reference/post-database-query) this is not possible at the moment. Querying a database always loads all properties and contents of all pages matching the filter.

- is that so?
- is yes, it a feature like this planned?
- is there a way around it?
- would querying only for some properties even make the request to notion resolve faster?

I am glad for any feedback